# Build with multiple sdk versions cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I recently ran into a problem where the sdk version I was build (23) was too new for the device I was testing on. I had to add a preference tag to target the sdk 19 to build with. However, if I want to support multiple platform versions and sdks, how can I specify multiple sdk versions to build with?

For instance, how can I build for 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 and have cordova choose the correct sdk version for my device when testing? How can this also be approached for ios? What is the best approach when trying to test and build cross platforms with a large range of sdks?

Comment: you have to use the latest SDK supported by cordova, right now 22, and it will work on all the android versions

Comment: For some reason when I was building with 22, I couldn't get google maps to work. Then I switched to 19 and it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can on Android, but not on iOS. This is a `minSdkVersion`, `maxSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`. At this time, it is [only available on *Phonegap Build*](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html#_android_only). On all *Cordova/Phonegap CLI* and *SDK*, you must change unpack change the setting a repack the `.apk`

**Addition: 2015-11-11** Since writing this post, I found a [flag available to iOS](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html#_ios_only). You can set `deployment-target`, tranlsates to the `MinimumOSVersion` in the *ipa Propertly List*. I hope you can excuse the error as iOS is not my primary development platform.

Best of Luck